# Using time in a powershell script for conditional loop

Tags: powershell, azure, timer, system

Here is my code:

```
        #make sure deployment is in running state
$deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -servicename $_serviceName -slot $_slotName
Write-Host "$_serviceName is in state $($deployment.status)"
while ($deployment.Status -ne "running")
{   
    Write-Host "wait 5 seconds before trying again" 
    Start-Sleep -s 5
    $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -servicename $_serviceName -slot $_slotName
    Write-Host "$_serviceName is in state $($deployment.status)"        
}
```

I want to put a condition in the while loop that if it's been running for lets say 2 hours, then it should exit. Can't seem to find out how to start a timer and keep a record of it in powershell.

Comment: You should take a look at using `stopwatch` and adding an additional condition via `&&` to your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, all I did was add a line to before your While loop, that also checks to make sure 2 hours have not yet passed during the While loop.

Depending on when you'd want to `break` out of the process, this may be the best option as it won't start a new loop again as soon as you hit a full 2 hours, and the loop is slated to restart.

```
#make sure deployment is in running state
$deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -servicename $_serviceName -slot $_slotName
Write-Host "$_serviceName is in state $($deployment.status)"
$StopWatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew() #new code
while (($deployment.Status -ne "running") -and ($StopWatch.Elapsed.Hours -lt 2)) #new code
{   
    Write-Host "wait 5 seconds before trying again" 
    Start-Sleep -s 5
    $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -servicename $_serviceName -slot $_slotName
    Write-Host "$_serviceName is in state $($deployment.status)"        
}
```